# How can i reorder a numpy array from high to low in another array without using in built functions

Tags: python, numpy

i am having a bit of trouble here, plus i am new to using numpy. what i want to do is reorder the array T in V from high to low and changing the highest number to -1 everytime in the array T without using unbuilt functions i would truly appreciate any help, thank you.

```
from copy import *
from numpy import *
import numpy



n = int(input("Entrez un entier: "))

def control_n(n):
    while n < 3 or n > 20:
        n = int(input("Rentrez un entier: "))
    return n


control_n(n)

# Initialisation du tableau, de taille n , type entier
t = array(n * [0], dtype=int)
v = array(n * [0], dtype=int)


            
def maximum(t, n):
    max = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if t[i] > max:
            max = t[i]
            print(max)
    return max, i


def rearrange(t, n, v):
    for i in range(n):
        max, indice = maximum(t, n)
        v[i] = max
        t[indice] = -1

    return (t, v)


    t1, v1 = rearrange(t, n, v)
    print(t1)
    print(v1

)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What is wrong (or right) about the code you present.  What do you mean by "in bult functions" or "unbuilt functions".  Why are you using `numpy` at all, if you don't want to use the functionality that it provides?  Stick with python lists if you want to work iteratively.  But even that has `sort` and `max` functions.

Comment: Also code with `input` calls is not reproducible, since it changes with the users input.  Include sample arrays in the question if you want us to test and improve your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the comments they are for my teacher, i had to make another loop because somehow it wasn't giving me the correct index number.

this is the full code.

```
from copy import *
from numpy import *
import numpy


n = int(input("Entrez un entier: "))

# controle de saisie sur n
def control_n(n):
    while n < 3 or n > 20:
        n = int(input("Rentrez un entier: "))
    return n


control_n(n)

# Initialisation du tableau, de taille n , type entier
t = array(n * [0], dtype=int)
v = array(n * [0], dtype=int)


# Procedure to remplissage du tableaux
def remplir_t(n, t):
    # un boucle pour la remplissage
    for i in range(n):
        # le entier qui doit etre postive
        b = int(input("Entrez un entier positive: "))
        while b < 0:
            b = int(input("Rentrez un entier positive: "))
        # si est il positive on le ajouter dans le tableaux sinon le utilisateur doit entrez un entier positive
        t[i] = b
    return t


remplir_t(n, t)

# Une fonction pour le decouvrir le maximum dans le array numpy
def maximum(t, n):
    max = 0
    # J'ai essayé d'utiliser le premier "i" de la boucle mais c'est toujours incorrect
    # alors j'ai fait une autre boucle pour trouver l'indice
    for i in range(n):
        if t[i] > max:
            max = t[i]
    for i in range(n):
        if max == t[i]:
            index = i
    return max, index


def rearrange(t, v, n):
    # J'ai copié le tableau comme vous l'avez dit merci pour l'aide.
    tableaux_intial = t.copy()
    for i in range(n):
        max, indice = maximum(t, n)
        # utilisez la fonction pour trouver le nombre maximum
        # puis ajoutez-le au tableau V et changez sa valeur en -1 dans le tableau T
        v[i] = max
        t[indice] = -1
    return t, v, tableaux_intial


t, v, tableaux_intial = rearrange(t, v, n)
# le affichage
print("Le tableaux avec les -1: ", t)
print("Le tableaux initial : ", tableaux_intial)
print("Le tableaux V: ", v)
```

Answer (score 1):

For *n == 5* I created both arrays as:

```
np.random.seed(1)
t = np.random.randint(1, 20, n)
v = np.random.randint(1, 20, n)
```

I used *np.random.seed* to get repeatable result.

The content of both arrays is:

```
array([ 6, 12, 13,  9, 10])
array([12,  6, 16,  1, 17]))
```

Then, to sort *v* array in the order of elements in *t*, you can run:

```
t1 = np.argsort(t)
v1 = v[t1]
```

The result is:

```
array([0, 3, 4, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
array([12,  1, 17,  6, 16])
```

Or shorter, without explicit creation of *t1*, you can run:

```
v1 = v[np.argsort(t)]
```

## Edit

To get the expected result **without** *Numpy* functions, you can proceed
as follows:

1. Define *maximum* function the following way:

   ```
   def maximum(t, n):
       max = 0
       iMax = -1
       for i in range(n):
           if t[i] > max:
               max = t[i]
               iMax = i
       return max, iMax
   ```

   A change compared to your solution is that this function returns the
   index of the max element in *t*, whereas your code returned the index
   of the **last** element (every time the same).
2. Define *rearrange* function as:

   ```
   def rearrange(t, n, v):
       t1 = np.copy(t)
       tInd = np.zeros_like(t)  # Table of indices
       for i in range(n):
           max, ind = maximum(t1, n)
           tInd[i] = ind
           t1[ind] = -1
       tInd = tInd[::-1]
       return tInd, v[tInd]
   ```

   The differences are that my code:

   - does not "destroy" source arrays (a good practice),
   - first computes the index array (*tInd*),
   - but it is generated as the list of indices starting from the
     **max** value, so to get the expected (ascending) order, it is reversed,
   - *v1* is generated in one go, as late as in *return* statement,
     retrieving elements of *v* in the order defined by *tInd*.

Now when you run `rearrange(t, n, v)`, you will get the expected result.

Comment: Well, i was asking if there is anyway to solve it without using any inbuilt functions, thanks anyway.

Comment: Your answer is useful but not related to what i was asking but i appreciate it.